# How to start redmine with a specific port from bash script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, shell, redmine, webrick

On my computer, I can start redmine by:

```
cd /usr/share/redmine
bundle exec rails server webrick -e production -p 3001
```

and this will start redmine just fine at port 3001. 
If I create a bash script, it always starts at port 3000, like the parameters were ignored. 
What am I doing wrong ?

This is what I have

```
#!/bin/bash

#exec /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera --no-sandbox $@
cd /usr/share/redmine

# Port from settings file will be ignored either way ... 

#bundle exec rails -p 3003 server webrick -e production
bundle exec rails server webrick -e production -p 3001
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickly checked that and found that your script works perfectly fine for me, changing the port in the script also changes the port WEBrick is listening at.

So nothing wrong with the script.

Comment: How do you run it 'as script'? Is the script executable (chmod 755)?